# "I'll carve into your ribs and leave you crying for a kiss" (Tessa Violet - Haze) - literal or metaphoric?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms, idiom-request

[*Haze*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCd9Z6cc_6Y) by Tessa Violet is a deep pop-folk piece that combines the struggle of someone who tries to honestly share their internal desires in a shallow society and the struggle to actually fully percieve the world with your all senses.

It starts with a quick retrospection on the apparently full life she lead before

> I used to be
>
> Overwhelmed by every little thing
>
> Torn apart, unraveled at the seams
>
> I think it rooted in the way I breathe

and continues describing the depressing circle of hedonism she fell into after that

> And I get drunk
>
> On a boy who asks me if I'm up
>
> Tells me he can't understand his luck
>
> To know me
>
> To love me
>
> To hold me
>
> Show up

and the mask of a perfect woman she can afford to wear with her popularity

> I'll be your empathetic savior
>
> Call me up, I'll meet you later
>
> You canpraise me for the way I always know just what to say
>
> **I'll carve into your ribs** and leave you crying for a kiss
>
> Just for kicks

Now, is she actually saying she would carve into your ribs (like a wood) or is there an idiom "carve in" I would imagine to mean something like "to dive in and root there"?

We have this idiom in Czech but I wasn't able to find it in any dictionary. Is there an idiom with this meaning? Thank you!

Comment: **carve into** is not an idiom. It refers to an act of cutting. We can "carve into a turkey" or a mining machine can "carve into a mountain". It can be used figuratively to mean "to begin something in earnest, to commence".  "We have a lot of work ahead of us. We might as well carve into it today."  We might as well get to doing it.

Comment: It seems a dark play on "snuggle into your side", domestic, comfortable **snuggle** replaced by painful **carve**.

Comment: If you're looking for a counterpart idiom for a Czech idiom, it might help if you gave us a sentence or two (in English translation) where the Czech idiom is used.  However, it is rather a stretch to say that "the question is widely applicable to a large audience" :)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo In Czech, we can say: "You have to repeat the vocabulary every day if you want it to carve into your memory." or "Anthropocentrism has carved into the way we talk about science." or "Šumava mountains have carved into my heart."

Comment: Examples from the literature: "See, I have *engraved* you on the palms of my hands; your walls are ever before me" Isaiah 49,16

Comment: That last example (engrave you) is not the same.  The first two are reflexives or mediopassives, the last a transitive, similar to **write**.  In English, we would say "if you want it **to be carved** into your memory"

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo so can I say: Anthropocentrism has been carved into the way we talk about science?

Comment: You can say that, and I think you would  be understood, but it's a somewhat idiosyncratic  way of expressing the idea.  Far more common would be **ingrained**.  "Anthropomorphism is ingrained into the way we think and talk about science." Not recommending the locution, just pointing it out. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has%20been%20ingrained%20into%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It certainly is not a common phrase. Physically, ribs are the protection for the heart. "Carve into your ribs" could mean forcefully accessing the heart.

However, the context is about feelings. So I would understand it as a metaphor for, "I'll make you fall in love with me", which would make sense, given the following phrase: "and leave you crying for a kiss".

Answer (score 2):

It could perhaps be related to the common phrase "dig/poke someone in the ribs", meaning a momentary, somewhat painful, action to forcefully draw someone's attention.

By extension then "carve into your ribs" suggests a permanent drawing of someone's attention.

In this context the 'pain' is not so much physical but emotional, amplified by the following phrase "and leave you crying for a kiss".

Hence the line as a whole suggests she has the power to captivate the guy and leave him desperate for more - though she might be doing it "just for kicks"!

Exquisite writing in my opinion, and also very dark!

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Nice answer.